# I wanna get data from my listview wich displays information from the database, because i want that data to be automatically bound in text fields

Tags: android

I get data from my sql lite database which is displayed in a list view. Now once a user clicks on the list view i want all the details to be automatically be fetched and should be bounded in text fields
For ex,
supposing i have a database of customer list having columns like name area address mobile and id as a primary key.
Now when i search from my app with a name say john, list view will show some selected details of all the jhons which are in my database.
now once a user clicks on one of the jhons i want his details to be bounded in my text fields.
I hope i have cleared the thing i want. if not please be free to ask
Please can anyone help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

First, make sure that you create the cursor correctly, that is, make sure that the columns you will be accessing are declared on your query statement via the correct projection. U

```
public static final String [] projection= {
    Database.Customers.Media._ID,       
    Database.Customers.Media.NAME,
    Database.Customers.Media.PHONE,
    Database.Customers.Media.EMAIL,
    Database.Customers.Media.ADDRESS,
};
```

Pass that via the query:

```
Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

And then to the adapter:

```
mAdapter = new YourCustomerAdapter(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.custom_list_view_layout, 
                        mCursor, 
                        from, to, 
                        SampleCursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
```

Your from and to really will not matter if you customize your adapters code. If you use the stock adapter however, they will limit your data.

Customer onBind:

```
@Override
 public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
     ViewHolder mHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

     if (mHolder == null) {
         mHolder = new ViewHolder();
         mHolder.name= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
         mHolder.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_phone);
     }

     mHolder.name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
     mHolder.phone .setText(cursor.getString(2));

 }
```

The more uiItems you want to fill, the more you would initialize via onBind, and then associate the cursor data to them.

If you try to access a column index, or a column that was not defined on your projection, meaning it is not part of the cursor, then you will get a runtime error.

Comment: i am receiving data from the database but it's not getting bind in my list view.

Answer (score 0):

What code you are using to get data from listview

make a row xml for your listview 
bind the row in baseAdapter
and set that baseadapter to listview 
It will display in listview

Comment: String[] from = new String[]{dbh.CId,dbh.CustName,dbh.CustArea,dbh.CustMobile};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.custdetailId,R.id.custdetailName,R.id.custdetailArea,R.id.custdetailMobile};
SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.customerdetail, c, from, to);
lv.setAdapter(sca);

Comment: umm actually, via this code i m getting my data and setting it to the list, but when i try to get more fields /coloumns form database, is shows error.

Comment: Post the error you are getting. Also, the views you want to fill with data, are those views inside the listview? or are those external elements?

Comment: like external text fields so that once i know that yeah he is my customer i dont have to write his details gain, it should automatically bind in my text fields.